# Issue for using aviary project in objective c for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, aviary

I had download the aviary code from [here](https://github.com/AviaryInc/iOS-SDK-Sample)

and try to run it.It give the below error.
I try to solve the issue by changing the **Architectures** to **Standard architectured (armv7,armv7s)**

I am using xcode 6.3 and ios target set as **ios8**

```
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFPhotoEditorController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFPhotoEditorCustomization", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFBlemish", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFBrightness", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFContrast", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFCrop", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFCropPresetHeight", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFCropPresetName", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFCropPresetWidth", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFDraw", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFEffects", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFEnhance", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFFrames", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFMeme", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFOrientation", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFRedeye", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFSaturation", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFSharpness", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFStickers", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFText", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
  "_kAFWhiten", referenced from:
      -[AFSDKDemoViewController setPhotoEditorCustomizationOptions] in AFSDKDemoViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Below are the list of framework in the code:-

```
CoreImage
Systeconfiguration
opengles
coretext
storekit
quartzcore
liblibsqlite
coredata
accelerate
assetslibrary
uikit
foundation
coregraphics
```

and aviarySDK

Please guide me if there is any else need to be added

Comment: Did you install all libraries? I think you're missing pne. As the compiler tells you; symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: @RobQuist thank you for the comment.I had edited by question and listed the framework added in the code.